# Scala mixin with object

Tags: scala

I have 3 trades that should be `mixin` into `two` different object. First object contains only first two traits, while second should contains all the traits.
I do not want to perform double initialization of `Trait1` and `Trait2`, so is it possible to use first object instance in second mixin, like this:

```
trait T1 { 
def m11 
def m12
def m13
}    
trait T2 {
def m21
def m22
def m23
}

def par = new T1 with T2 {
def m11 = new M11Class()
def m12 = new M12Class()
def m13 = new M13Class()
def m21 = new M21Class()
def m22 = new M22Class()
def m23 = new M23Class()
}
    def child = new T1 with T2 with TraitChild {
def m11 = new M11Class()
def m12 = new M12Class()
def m13 = new M13Class()
def m21 = new M21Class()
def m22 = new M22Class()
def m23 = new M23Class()
/*init 3*/

}
```

I'd like:

```
def child = par with TraitChild { /*init 3 only*/ }
```

So in general: 
I do not want to invoke my 6 constructors 2 times.

Comment: Do you mean, with similar syntax (using anonymous classes) or in general?

Comment: similar or in general. I just want to solve problem.

Comment: When you say you don't want to "invoke [a] constructor" more than once, do you mean you don't want *a second invocation to happen at runtime*, or do you mean that you don't want *to write the code that calls the constructor twice*? Is every reference to, for example, `par.m11` supposed to call the `new M11Class()` constructor again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class or trait with an implementation you want to "rubber stamp" onto multiple objects:

```scala
trait Stamp extends T1 with T2 {
  def m11 = new M11Class()
  def m12 = new M12Class()
  /* ... */
}

val par = new Stamp { }

val child = new Stamp with TraitChild {
  /* define implementation for TraitChild */
}
```

In this example if you made `Stamp` a class instead of a trait, you could create `par` with just `new Stamp`.

You can even use local variables in a stamp trait, so that the methods return the same objects as values even when called on different objects:

```scala
def createObjects(): (T1 with T2, T1 with T2 with TraitChild) = {
  val x11 = new M11Class()
  val x12 = new M12Class()
  /* ... */

  trait Stamp extends T1 with T2 {
    def m11 = x11
    def m12 = x12
    /* ... */
  }

  val par = new Stamp { }

  val child = new Stamp with TraitChild {
    /* define implementation for TraitChild */
  }

  (par, child)
}
```

Comment: yes, thx. I was expected to use more elegant solution, but seems i'll use this one.